# Getting the general log to work in MySQL 5.6.8

Tags: mysql

I can't get the general log to work in this version of MySQL.

I added the following lines to `/usr/my.cnf`:

```
general_log = 1
general_log_file = "/var/log/mysql.log"
```

Then restarted the server:

```
[root@localhost ~]# service mysql restart
Shutting down MySQL.. SUCCESS!
Starting MySQL. SUCCESS!
```

The settings seem to be taken into account:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'general_log%';
+------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value              |
+------------------+--------------------+
| general_log      | ON                 |
| general_log_file | /var/log/mysql.log |
+------------------+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

But the log is never created:

```
[root@localhost ~]# mysqladmin flush-logs
[root@localhost ~]# ls -al /var/log/mysql.log
ls: cannot access /var/log/mysql.log: No such file or directory
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may seem like a clugy band-aid, but try the following for now...

```
service mysql stop
touch /var/log/mysql.log
chown mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql.log
service mysql start
```

This should work. Keep in mind MySQL 5.6.8 is not GA certified.

Please look back at the database home folder (run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir';`)

Go to the folder and see if a default general log appeared.

You could also try changing it to

```
general_log = 1
general_log_file = mysql.log
```

and see if the `mysql.log` appears in your datadir folder after restarting mysql

Comment: You were right, this was a permission problem. Thanks!