# Cannot get mysql slowqueries to log

Tags: linux, mysql

I added this stuff to the my.cnf file.

```
log_slow_queries = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 4
```

Then I created a directory in /var/log/ called mysql.
Then I restarted the mysql service.

But slow queries are not logging.  I know there are slow queries taking place because when I type this: mysqladmin proc stat -u root -p
I get some stuff and one of them says - Slow Queries: 845

The only thing I thought might be an issue was that I had created the /var/log/mysql directory as root, so maybe the mysql service doesn't have rights to write to that dir.  So I did chown mysql on that directory but still no file has been created in that dir.

Answer (score 1):

see this: [slow_query_log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_slow_query_log)

I think you might have to enable slow query logging by setting slow-query-log=1

Also try this

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'log_slow_queries';
```

If this reports ON, then the slow query log is enabled.

In this case, you might try lowering long_query_time.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I ran that query and it said log_slow_queries = ON.  I'll lower the threshold but I still think it is a problem with being able to write the file somehow.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out.  When I do SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%slow%' I discovered that my log file was in a different spot.  I think that there might be another my.cnf file floating in another dir that was actually the one it was using.

Comment: In ubuntu I would go and see /etc/init.d/mysql file to see which config file is being used, this is if you are using mysql through init or do ps aux | grep mysql to see if it has been started with a custom config file

Answer (score 0):

If you are having rights issues with `/var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log`, please try this:

```
service mysql stop
touch /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
chown mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
service mysql stop
```

I recommended this before : [Getting the general log to work in MySQL 5.6.8](https://serverfault.com/questions/453035/getting-the-general-log-to-work-in-mysql-5-6-8/453101#453101)